# Which component defines the default DB locking type?

Tags: java, database, locking

When a transaction starts, there are many different types of locking (e.g. Optimist locking, lock entire table, lock only the row being changed, etc)

If I don't specify the one I want, what defines the default type? The database? The (Java) connector implementation? The API for DB connection? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java app controls DB only thru JDBC methods. The standard way to control table locking is

```
Connection.setTransactionIsolation
```

it depends on DBMS how it will uses locks to secure requested transaction isolation level